# Users' physical characteristics - design

Tags: database-design, users

I have to build a database for an employment agency. For each user will be stored physical characteristics like height, weight, hair color...(9 fields in total).

I thought I could just build a `physical_data` table linked to `users` table, but what if the number of fields changes in the next months (client needing can change based on search trends)?

Do I have to "continuously" shrink/stretch this table potentially risking inconsistencies (me and developers are not in the same web agency)?

I event thought about a `user_physical_meta` table with just 3 fields (meta_key, meta_value, data_type): this will give me flexibility but seems like a patch, not a real solution.

What design should I choose for `users` physical characteristics?

Comment: Ah, the daily EAV question

Answer (score 0):

The meta table gives you flexibility of design (new "fields" are added and removed using DML instead of DDL), but its inefficiencies means it is not very scalable and it can be an absolute bear to maintain. Depending on how many users will be tracked, it could work well for you. The only way to know for sure is to build and test it.